# jquery use diferente variables in the same <p> from fields from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

http://prntscr.com/ir16ez

I have a problem, i cannot put diferent amounts in my shopping cart because when i choose a quantity, the program take what i choose and does the result for money etc,(working fine here) and brings the quantity to the shopping cart named "encomenda" but when i add a diferent item, the quantity changes to all instead of changing to only one, ssry from my english

> //shopping cart html

```
<div class="rightdiv">carrinho
<div id="encomenda" class="expandContent">
    <h3 class="header">
        <div class="headerColumn1">Encomenda</div>
        <div class="headerColumn2 expand"><img src="img/plus.png"/></div>
        <div class="expandedContentClearFloat"></div>
    </h3>
    <div class="expandedContent">
        {% for item in data %}
        <div class="product-removal">
            <article class="product">
                <header>
                    <img src="{{ item.img|e }}" class="iconcomp">
                </header>

                <div class="content">
                    <h1>{{ item.marca|e }}</h1>
                    {{ item.descr|e }}
                </div>
                <footer class="content">

                    <h2 class="full-price fixed fixed-encomenda">
                        {{ item.preco_unit|e }}€
                    </h2>
   <p class='quantidade'  ></p> **//shows the amount here**

                    <a class='pull-right adicionar adicionar-encomenda' data-id='{{ item.id|e }}'
                        data-preco='{{ item.preco_unit|e }}' data-modelo="{{ item.modelo|e }}" data-marca="{{ item.marca|e }}" data-descr="{{ item.descr|e }}">
                        <h2 class="full-price">
                            {{ item.preco_unit|e }}€
                        </h2>
                    </a>
                    <h2 class="price">
                        {{ item.preco_unit|e }}
                    </h2>

                </footer>
            </article>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <h1 id='valor_configuracao' class='pull-right' value='data-preco'>0</h1>
    </div>
<input type="button" id="enviar" value="enviar" data-mensagem="ola">
</div>
</div>
```

> //add disco for example

```
$('.adicionar-disco').click(function () {
    id = $(this).data('id');

    var allExceptClicked = $('.adicionar-disco').not(this);
    AdicionarItem(allExceptClicked, "disco", "disco2");
    $(this).data('quantidade', parseFloat($(this).parent().find("span.qt").text()));
    $(this).parent().parent().find("button.close-disco").data('quantidade', parseFloat($(this).parent().find("span.qt").text()));
    preco = preco + ($(this).data("preco")* $(this).data('quantidade'));
      p=$(this).data('quantidade'); **//receive in p the amount**
    var rounded = Math.round((preco) * 100) / 100;
    $('#valor_configuracao').html(rounded);
    $('.adicionar-encomenda').each(function () {

        var productRow = $(this).parent().parent();
        var i = $(this).data('id');
        if (i == id) {
            productRow.show();
            alert(p);
            $(".quantidade").text(p);**//give the <p> variable that is in the "encomenda" p that has the amount needed**
            //$("p").attr(".quantidade",p);
            //Marcar item como selecionado
            $(this).attr("data-selecionado","sim");
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Where is your html code?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Can you please explain briefly?

Comment: i will edit and add my html code

Comment: What is displayed instead of the desired result. Also, no PHP here so you can remove that tag

Comment: when i choose a quantity, the program take what i choose and does the result for money etc,(working fine here) and brings the quantity to the shopping cart named "encomenda" but when i add a diferent item, the quantity changes to all instead of changing to only one, ssry from my english

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle or provide a link so I can check your code?

Answer (score 0):

the statement `$(".quantidade").text(p)` set the same value at all element with class="quantitade", and all item of your chart have class="quantitade".
You should uniquely identify the div where you want to set the value, with id attribute, if possible, generated with the product id.

Comment: but it shows in the same div, is one div to all that is added, understand me ?

Comment: You create `<p class='quantidade'  ></p>` for each element in cart. Then you set a value in every element with class='quantitade', with the statement `$(".quantidade").text(p)`, the same value for all these element.